# Importing cpyherl files into Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I got a `sample-data.cypherl` file that looks like this:

```
CREATE (:Factory {id: "200", name: "Factory Alpha", location: "New York"});
CREATE (:Warehouse {id: "201", name: "Warehouse Bravo", location: "Berlin"});
CREATE (:Retailer {id: "202", name: "Retailer Charlie", location: "Tokyo"});
CREATE (:Warehouse {id: "203", name: "Warehouse Delta", location: "Sydney"});
CREATE (:Retailer {id: "204", name: "Retailer Echo", location: "Toronto"});

MATCH (u:Factory), (v:Warehouse) WHERE u.id = "200" AND v.id = "201" CREATE (u)-[:SUPPLIES]->(v);
MATCH (u:Factory), (v:Warehouse) WHERE u.id = "200" AND v.id = "203" CREATE (u)-[:SUPPLIES]->(v);
MATCH (u:Warehouse), (v:Retailer) WHERE u.id = "201" AND v.id = "202" CREATE (u)-[:DISTRIBUTES_TO]->(v);
MATCH (u:Warehouse), (v:Retailer) WHERE u.id = "201" AND v.id = "204" CREATE (u)-[:DISTRIBUTES_TO]->(v);
MATCH (u:Warehouse), (v:Retailer) WHERE u.id = "203" AND v.id = "202" CREATE (u)-[:DISTRIBUTES_TO]->(v);
MATCH (u:Warehouse), (v:Retailer) WHERE u.id = "203" AND v.id = "204" CREATE (u)-[:DISTRIBUTES_TO]->(v);
```

The fist batch of queries create nodes for factories, warehouses, and retailers. The second batch queries create relationships between these nodes, representing the supply chain connections. So it hoes something like this:

- Factory Alpha supplies Warehouse Bravo and Warehouse Delta.
- Warehouse Bravo distributes to Retailer Charlie and Retailer Echo.
- Warehouse Delta distributes to Retailer Charlie and Retailer Echo.

I know that I can simply run this as a query in Memgraph Lab, but what when I will have larger files with thousands of rows? I think that browsers have some limit when it comes to copy/pasting data info fields.

I have two instances of Memgraph for learning, native Ubuntu and one running in Docker (this is Memgraph Platform image).

How can I import cypherl files directly into them, without copy/paste method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Memgraph Lab you can run the following command on your Ubuntu installation:

```
mgconsole < sample-data.cypherl
```

This tells to `mgconsole` to use `sample-data.cypherl` as the input.

If you have Memgraph Lab go to Import & Export and import the `sample-data.cypherl` from there.

For Docker version you need to tun this command:

```
docker run -i --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform --host HOST < sample-data.cypherl
```

Replace `HOST` with the IP address of your Docker container. You can find it out using the command `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' DOCKER-CONTAINER-ID`.

And you get `DOCKER-CONTAINER-ID` using `docker ps`.